# output the count of the items as header pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my dataframe:
'''

```
 customer product     product1
0        A    hats        shoes
1        A   socks        shoes
2        B   socks        shoes
3        C    hats        shoes
4        C    None  accessories
5        B   socks        shoes
6        A    hats        shoes
7        C    None  accessories
```

'''
I want to output something like this:

```
customer    shoes   hats    socks   accessories
A             #       #        #    #
B             #       #        #    #
C             #       #        #    #
```

I tried group by like this:
'''

```
dfB.set_index('customer').groupby(['product', 'product1']).agg({'product':['count'], 'product1':['count']}) '''
```

I got output like this:

'''

```
 product product1
                   count    count
product product1                 
 hats   shoes          3        3
 socks  shoes          3        3
```

'''

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `melt` then `pivot_table`

```
# df = df.replace('None', None) # If `'None'` and not `None`

(df.melt('customer', value_name='product')
   .pivot_table(index='customer', columns='product', aggfunc='size'))

product   accessories  hats  shoes  socks
customer                                 
A                 NaN   2.0    3.0    1.0
B                 NaN   NaN    2.0    2.0
C                 2.0   3.0    1.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

IIUC

we can set the index to 'customer' then stack the dataframe allowing you to do a aggregation with `value_counts`

```
df2 = df.set_index('customer').stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack()
```

-

```
print(df2)
          None  accessories  hats  shoes  socks
customer                                       
A          NaN          NaN   2.0    3.0    1.0
B          NaN          NaN   NaN    2.0    2.0
C          2.0          2.0   1.0    1.0    NaN
```

if you don't care about `None` you can convert it to a true null value and it will be ignored in the groupby

```
print(df.replace('None',np.nan).set_index('customer').stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack())

          accessories  hats  shoes  socks
customer                                 
A                 NaN   2.0    3.0    1.0
B                 NaN   NaN    2.0    2.0
C                 2.0   1.0    1.0    NaN
```